# How to shrink a UIView's size to zero if hidden, in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

If you set text to a UILabel it will update its content size to get it all displayed. I want to do the same with a custom button. But instead of changing the text, I want to shrink the button to zero size, if it is being hidden. (analog to Android's VISIBILITY_GONE)

So I am again playing with the Autolayout system and could not solve this one:

In my XIB file I have defined a button. The button is a custom subclass and it overrides `intrinsicContentSize`. If the button is hidden or its alpha is set to 0, the intrinsicContentSize will be (0,0) and the real intrinsic size otherwise.

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize{
    if (self.zeroSizeIfHidden && (self.hidden || self.alpha == 0)) {
        return CGSizeZero;
    }
    CGSize const size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return size;
}
```

Now I try to tell the layout system to update all related layout constraints and failed with that. The button should be visible in a UITableViewCell - but it doesn't. It simply pops up on the very next "fade" animation and hides. And no, I can't simply remove it from screen if unwanted. The cell grows and shrinks when the user taps it.

This is what I've tried so far, from my UITableViewCell:

```
if (self.button.hidden || self.button.alpha == 0) {
    self.button.hidden = NO;
    self.button.alpha = 1;
    [self.button invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [self.button setNeedsLayout];
    [self.button layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.button.superview invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    [self.button.superview setNeedsLayout];
    [self.button.superview layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

What did I miss? Is there something I have not yet tried? I think I need some Autolayout guru's help.

Background: The cell itself is built using autolayout. It shows some piece of information and will expand to full information when you tap it. Along with the full information, the button should be displayed - under several circumstances.

Edit:

**I am looking for some idea, how I can force the Autolayout mechanism to query the new size of my button.**

(To see it in action: It is the "Info & Documentation" table view of 'POI Toolbox'. Just tap the "i" button in the lower right of the map screen. (AppStore: https://apps.apple.com/de/app/poi-toolbox/id1547993322))

Comment: Try to put together a [mre]. We have no idea what your view hierarchy is, what constraints you have set, how you're telling the UI to change, etc. (and you really can't expect people to install some random app and try to figure out what you're talking about)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue with the Autolayout constraints. Each cell uses a custom background view. So the BG view of the cell below hid the button while the button itself was simply placed outside of the visible area.

This implementation is correct for the custom button:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize{
    if (self.zeroSizeIfHidden && (self.hidden || self.alpha == 0)) {
        return CGSizeZero;
    }
    CGSize const size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return size;
}
```

Or if you prefer the short variant and don't need to debug:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize{
    return (self.zeroSizeIfHidden && (self.hidden || self.alpha == 0))
        ? CGSizeZero : [super intrinsicContentSize];
}
```

And for the cell, this is enough:

```
// Code...
if (self.button.hidden || self.button.alpha == 0) {
    self.button.hidden = NO;
    self.button.alpha = 1;
}
// Code...
```

The button size is being updated, as the table view reloads the row.